# How do i change the directory of the Vite manifest in Laravel, or how do I serve two Vite projects in on Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, vite

I want to have two frontends: app and admin for my project (laravel). I want to use vite. Using ChatGPT it said to have the following config:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [laravel(["resources/js/app/main.jsx"]), react()],
    build: {
        outDir: "public/js/app",
        rollupOptions: {
            input: "resources/js/app/main.jsx",
        },
    },
});
```

But when I build the project, Laravel gives me error: Vite manifest not found. That's because it looks for manifest file in public/build, however i have public/js/app.

I want to use public/js/app and public/js/admin as my configurations.

On the other hand, if there is some other way to serve two vite projects, I am welcome to know it!

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer.
In welcome.blade.php

```
{{
    Vite::useBuildDirectory('js/app')
}}
```

in vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            buildDirectory: "js/app", // Customize the build directory...
            input: ["resources/js/app/main.jsx"], // Specify the entry points...
        }),
        react(),
    ],
});
```